# get_defined_vars() inside a class

Tags: php

How do i get all defined global variables inside a class function?

When I call the `get_defined_vars()` function inside a class method I only get an empty object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Define variables outside the PHP class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505735/define-variables-outside-the-php-class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

via => [Define variables outside the PHP class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505735/define-variables-outside-the-php-class)

```
class Foo {
    function bar(){
       var_dump($GLOBALS);
    }
}
Foo::bar();
```

outputs :

```
array(8) {
  ["GLOBALS"]=>
    array(8) {
      ["GLOBALS"]=>
      *RECURSION*
      ["_POST"]=>
      array(0) {
      }
/*snip*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `get_class_vars(__CLASS__)` if you want the predefined variables & values (those values defined and set as default before an object initialized).

Use `get_object_vars($this)` if you want all the variables (instance variables) including those which are created temporarily for a particular object while executing any method of the class.

I know these are not really the things you need. Its `$GLOBALS` that you need answered yourself. But I just gave these methods for your reference so that may be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [`get_class_vars()`](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php)?

Comment: sorry maybe i had explain it wrong, i meant the wide site vars, like if get_defined_vars() was called in the main script.

Comment: I'm not aware of that being possible, because every function / method makes own scope. get_defined_vars() does return the variables defined in your class method, if you have any, but this is not helping you.