# Array from a file not required

Tags: php, arrays

I have a file called settings.php where I define an array like this:

```
$ITEMS = array(
  'a' => 'b',
  'a' => 'b',
  'a' => 'b',
  'a' => 'b',
);
```

and a class in another file module.php

```
namespace Blah;

require_once 'settings.php';

class Blah {
   public function blabla() {
      global $ITEMS;
      foreach ($ITEMS as $item) {
         ...
      }
   }    
}
```

Both files are in the same folder (which probably has no significance).
The file is required with no problem, however I get an exception in the foreach due to $ITEMS being NULL.

I can't seem to get what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Comment: How did you prove that the include process actually worked?

Comment: Well, since I am using require_once, there should be an exception if require does not succeed, which doesn't happen.

Comment: wouldnt the path of settings.php depend on where your calling your class from? eg. if you have index.php in root, then call your class from index.php and your class is in another directory, will it not look for settings in the root? would it not be best to hardcode the settings into your class?

Comment: Hmmm, you seem to be correct, that is, when I require the file in index.php, everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: As you are not catching an exception, and if you have error_reporting turned down/off you'd have to go looking in your logfiles for evidence of the error.  Doing any/all of these things in a dev environment is therefore a good idea if you want to avoid making these kind of assumptions, and therefore speed up the process of development. HTHY

Comment: @JanaBanana checkout this demo: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kpw-iht in-which one element is printed out only.

Comment: This is a scope issue, check out this thread; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505735/define-variables-outside-the-php-class